# get Y value given X value in AM Charts JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amcharts, amcharts4

I am using AMCharts for my project, what I want is to accomplish this:

given **1. data points:**

```
const data = [{x: 23, y: 0},{x: 24, y: 0},{x: 25, y: 23},...,{x: 26, y: 24}]
```

I want to extract any Y value given X value from the series...

Partial code I am using to create chart:

```
        this.chart = am4core.create(this.chartDiv, am4charts.XYChart);

        this.title = this.chart.titles.create();

        // chartData is just an array of x,y values
        this.chart.data = this.props.chartData;

        const X_AXIS = this.chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
        X_AXIS.title.text = "X VALUES";

        const Y_AXIS = this.chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
        Y_AXIS.title.text = "Y VALUES";

        this.series = this.chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        this.series.dataFields.valueX = "xValue";
        this.series.dataFields.valueY = "yValue";

        // cursor
        this.chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
        this.chart.cursor.xAxis = X_AXIS;
        this.chart.cursor.yAxis = Y_AXIS;
        this.chart.cursor.snapToSeries = this.series;
```

How can I accomplish this? Say Y value for X = 24 in JS (something like this.series.get(25))

Answer (score 1):

Why not just search through the data using the `Array.prototype.find` method since you're generating your points based on the data array anyways.

```js
const data = [{x: 23, y: 0},{x: 24, y: 0},{x: 25, y: 23},{x: 26, y: 24}];

console.log(data.find(item => item.x === 23).y);
```

Comment: Thing is, the data is not complete, for example my dataset only has integers whereas am charts interpolates values in between. so if x = 23.5, whats y? i need it from the chart.

Comment: If you are only going to step by 0.5 x units you can just take the y values of the points to the right and left of x = 23.5 add them, then divide by two.

Comment: that was just an example, the line could be any 2d polynomial and I'll need any point in between...